# Remove over 100,000 rows from mysql table - server crashes

Tags: mysql

I have a question when I try to remove over 100,000 rows from a mysql table the server freezes and non of its websites can be accessed anymore!

I waited 2 hours and then restarted the server and restored the account.

I used following query:

```
DELETE FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000
```

-

```
SELECT* FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000
```

works perfectly

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are there any cascade deletes or triggers involved?  Are there possible open transactions locking the table (or related tables) during the delete?  This delete should really run in seconds.

Comment: @mellamokb sorry but I dont know what cascade deletes or triggers, what I can say is that I did not change anything on the standard settings: SELECT* FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000 works perfectly

Comment: deleting 100k should take few minutes. If it takes 2 hours something is wrong and I suggest you investigating and learn from it. What's the table engine ? how many records are on that table ? are you deleting on a myisam table on production (possible table locking) ? Do you have an index on link_id / or it is the PK ? is your mysql server overloaded ? what do you mean with "restored the account" ? do you have LOTS on other tables of data and innnodb configured without innodb_file_per_table ? are mysql params (like key_buffer for myisam and buffer pool for innob tuned OK) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete the rows in smaller sets. A quick script that deletes 1000 rows at a time should see you through.

Comment: DELETE FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` > 10000 and  `link_id` < 20000

Comment: DELETE FROM `pligg_links` WHERE `link_id` >= 20000 and  `link_id` < 30000

Comment: The options from Nesim will do just what you need. You can either do them manually or write a script in your favourite language to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

"Delete from" can be very expensive for large data sets.

I recommend using partitioning.

This may be done slightly differently in PostgreSQL and MySQL, but in PostgreSQL you can create many tables that are "partitions" of the larger table or on a partition.  Queries and whatnot can be run on the larger table.  This can greatly increase the speed with which you can query given you partition correctly.  Also, you can delete a partition by simply dropping it.  This happens very very quickly because it is somewhat equivalent to dropping a table.

Documentation for table partitioning can be found here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index on link_id column.
And try to delete with chunks like 10.000 in a time.
Deleting from table is very costy operation.

Comment: if you usually sort of the link_id column then add the following line to the create table command `primary key(link_id)`

Comment: @qwerty9967 like this? DELETE FROM primary key(link_id) WHERE link_id > 10000

Comment: @Chriswede No.  As I said, this is part of the CREATE TABLE command.  If you want to create a second index later, then you can use the CREATE INDEX command http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html.  I still recommend partitioning as a better solution.